# system.out.println equivalent in flash

Tags: flash

Is there an equivalent method to print stuff out in flash cs3? Im used to using System.out.println() in java

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `trace()` function which will trace to the debug console if you're using the debug player (right-click on the SWF - if you see an option named "Debugger" you're using the debug version - otherwise go here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html).

Where it comes out depends on the IDE; the console window in Eclipse/FlashBuilder and the Output panel in Flash/FlashDevelop.

If you're looking for something more along the lines of printf, then you can check out this project: http://code.google.com/p/printf-as3/ which gives you the same result.